# Why is Prometheus only showing my manager node for docker?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, prometheus

I'm new to using Prometheus and I would really appreciate some help. I have a swarm of machines with 1 manager and 7 workers. The manager is on a digital ocean instance and the workers are physical machines on my local network.

The problem is when I go to the Grafana dashboard only 1 node is being detected. When I visit the prometheus targets url at port 9090, I see 8 endpoints but only 1 is up. The rest have an error that says "context_deadline_exceeded".

On each machine, I have set the metrics address to 0.0.0.0:9323 and experimental mode is set to true. I have also enabled port 2376 on the machines, 7946, and 4789.

Any suggestions to get metrics for the other nodes is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Could you please share your scraper configs?

Comment: @opHASnoNAME I am using swarmprom and the docker-compose.yml file contains the config. You can view the repo here: https://github.com/stefanprodan/swarmprom